# Uncaught TypeError: Not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have modified a fiddle that I found online, and would like to run it on my page. However I get an Uncaught TypeError when trying to do so. Can you help me figure out the problem?

Link to my page: http://goo.gl/7jTAya
Link to jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZLL/1655/

Thanks already!

Here is my code:

```
var sliders = $("#sliders .slider");

sliders.each(function() {
    var value = parseInt($(this).text(), 10),
    availableTotal = 100;

    $(this).empty().slider({
        value: 0,
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        range: "max",
        step: 10,
        animate: 100,
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            // Update display to current value
            $(this).siblings().text(ui.value + ' %');

            // Get current total
            var total = 0;

            sliders.not(this).each(function() {
                total += $(this).slider("option", "value");
            });

            // Need to do this because apparently jQ UI
            // does not update value until this event completes
            total += ui.value;

            var max = availableTotal - total;

            // Update each slider
            sliders.not(this).each(function() {
            var t = $(this),
                value = t.slider("option", "value");

            t.slider("option", "max", max + value)
                .siblings().text(value + ' %');
            t.slider('value', value);
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Slider plugin reference missing!

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you please elaborate? It works here:
http://jsfiddle.net/Y5ZLL/1655/

Comment: If you can see **Frameworks and Extensions & External Resources** tab on the left, `jQuery-ui` is included. Which is not present in your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must include the JS file where the Slider function is defined.
Maybe [jQuery Slider](https://jqueryui.com/slider/), from jQueryUI?

```
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
```

Here is the [working demo](http://jsbin.com/qoyazoyoca/1/edit?html,js,console,output).

Comment: Thank you very much for helping me out. I would like to output the value of each value to the console every time a slider changes. Can you help me add this? Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much!! I am trying to use your suggestion to insert the value in 3 different fields on each update of sliders. However, I need to know which slider gives which values. Any way I can get the number/name of the changed slider as well, so I can put the value in the correct field? Hope it makes sense..

I was trying to use console.log(jQuery(this).index()); to output the index of the slider, but cant get it to work :-)

Comment: Updtated the DEMO. See the console.log( $(this).parents().attr('class') )

Comment: If you are ok with the answer, could you mark my answer as accepted? http://jsbin.com/movocanebe/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Of course. Thanks again! But I dont see any changes in the demo? :-)

Comment: Yes, i've forgot the correct link: http://jsbin.com/movocanebe/1/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: I know I am being very difficult now.. But one last thing - can I get only the identification of the change slider, and the value of that one slider? :-)

Comment: Mmmmmm, i'dont think it is so simple.

Comment: Got what i needed. Thanks for your effort!
http://jsbin.com/xotixanuwe/2/edit?html,js,console,output

Comment: Sorry to disturb again. The jQuery UI slider is pretty unstable when changing it a lot of times in a row. Can you help me implement an alternative instead?

Maybe http://refreshless.com/nouislider/ ?

Comment: In these case i suggest to try to develop it from scratch, not with plugin. Make a try...

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `jquery-ui.js` library. Just add this:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```